# “You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run: libc.so.6” Standard fixes not working

Tags: steam, 32-bit, mesa

Recently set myself up with 14.04 LTS and when I install steam and try to run it, I get this message in terminal.

Steam needs to install these additional packages:

```
libgl1-mesa-dri:i386, libgl1-mesa-glx:i386, libc6:i386
```

When I enter my password for this, I get this series of events in terminal:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 : Depends: libglapi-mesa:i386 (= 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.4)
 unity-control-center : Depends: libcheese-gtk23 (>= 3.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libcheese7 (>= 3.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
Press return to continue:
```

I press enter, and get that familiar old

```
You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run:
libGL.so.1'
```

I have tried `sudo apt-get update`, `sudo apt-get install libc6-i386` to no success, and otherwise can't find any helpful information.

Comment: what does this show? `apt-cache policy libgl1-mesa-dri*` You should be using either the 14.04.1 or 14.04.3 image to install Ubuntu. In the case of the later then it uses `libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-vivid` & if needed on a 64 bit install `libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-vivid:i386`. Steam works fine here, am on 14.04.3 with lts-vivid HWE stack

Answer (score 0):

In a terminal:

```
sudo apt install steam
```